# find more than one index of a value in a C 2-D array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am quite new in C, but I have some good skills in matlab. In matlab I can use `[x,y]=find(matrix==any_value)` and it returns me lots of `x` and `y`-indices of a given value if this value is present in matrix.

I tried some functions as find, but what I read about it is that it only returns the index of the first occurrence of the value in the matrix.

Suppose I have a 2-D array of double in C with some repeated values, how can I find the `x` and `y` coordinates of a repeated value in this matrix?

Comment: You can use [for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) with an approriate function fn.

Comment: Some hints: Have you considered using the `std::find` algorithm in `<algorithm>`? You can specify a search range. When combined with a loop, you can easily iterate over all occurences. Also note, that since `C++11` there are also `std::find_if` and `std::find_if_not`, which are more general. You can also wrap the `std::find` loop into your own iterator like it is done in boost's `find_iterator`, which is closer to what you have in MATLAB.

Comment: Is this question regarding C or C++? Question and title indicate C, but tag is C++, which seems to prompt possibly irrelevant C++ answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in C you can return only one value. The results are couples, and you need more than one. I'd declare a point struct and fill an array of those objects; the function will return the number of results found... to get you started, something like:

```
struct point {
  int x;
  int y;
};

int find_stuff(int* mat[], int dimX, int dimY, int desired, struct point out[])
{
    int ret=0;
    int x, y;

    for(y=0; y<;dimY; y++)
        for (x=0; x<dimX; x++)
            if (mat[y][x] == desired) {
                out[ret].x = x;
                out[ret].y = y;
                ret++;
            }

    return ret;
}

void test_the_function(int* mat[], int dimX, int dimY, int desired)
{
    struct point results[100];
    int i,n;

    n = find_stuff(mat, dimX, dimY, desired, results);

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%i\t(%i, %i)\n", i, results[i].x, results[i].y);
}
```

Comment: It's a bit static but OP said he.she was new to C, so that's a lead at least.

Comment: Exceptyon, what I need in your code is the matrix out[] and the int ret, can I return both of them in the find_stuff function?

Comment: @mad:in c a function returns only one value (and usually it is not a good idea to return an array)... you have no choice other than fill the array and return the final length

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write your own function, as C does not have a built-in function for finding elements.
This function would not "break" after finding the first instance, but continue till the end of the list.

Keep a blank array of indices. `indices[]`
Whenever you find the element, push it into this indices array.
At the end of the function, you'll have all the indices neatly stored in an array of x,y coordinates (or indices).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    const double val = 3.14;
    double a[100][100];
    /* ... initialize a somehow ... */
    vector<pair<int,int>> pos;

    for ( int x = 0; x < 100; ++x )
        for ( int y = 0; y < 100; ++y )
            if ( a[x][y] == val )
                pos.push_back( make_pair(x,y) );

    std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), [](pair<int,int> p){
        cout << '(' << p.first << ',' << ')' << endl;
    });
}
```